# How can I figure out what package name is for the default Home launcher on a device?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm trying to find out how I can detect what the actual package name is on a given device that it uses for its stock Home launcher.

On most devices it's pretty obvious, but I have a couple (Galaxy Note 2 and LG Spectrum) where I can't for the life of me deduce what app package is their Home.

The reason I need this is that I am making an app that installs itself as the Home app and I want to give the user the ability to get back to the native Home, so I want to launch it manually for them.

Is there some way to get this info from the device itself or some programatic way to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tests for all the devices I'm currently testing with... if the if clause doesn't cover some device, you'll need look at the log to see what the package name is and add some relevant portion of its name to the string matcher.

```
void getDefaultLauncher() {



    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = ((PackageManager)getPackageManager()).queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);      


    //String className = null;
    for(ResolveInfo ri : list){
        L.d("FOUND NATIVE LAUNCH ACTIVITY " + ri.activityInfo.packageName);
        if(ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.lge") ||  ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("android") || ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("motorola.homescreen")  || ri.activityInfo.packageName.contains("htc.launcher") ){
            L.d("LAUNCHING " + ri.activityInfo.packageName);
            startSpecificActivity(ri);
            return;
        }
    }

    L.d("DIDN'T FIND MATCHING HOME APP");       
}

public void startSpecificActivity(ResolveInfo launchable) {

         ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;

         ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,   activity.name);

        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        i.setComponent(name);
        startActivity(i);    
    }
```